# Product of unbounded functions

Tags: functions, upper-lower-bounds

I am supposed to find out if a product of two unbounded functions can be a bounded function. Also if a composition of two unbounded functions can be a bounded function. Could anyone answer these questions and tell me why? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\frac 1x$

$g(x)=x$ and $h(x)=e^x$.

$f$  , $g$ and $h$ are unbounded at $(0,\infty)$

but $f(x)g(x)=1$
and
$f(h(x))=e^{-x}$.

thus

$|(f.g)(x)|\le 1$ and
$|f(h)(x)|\le 1$

hence, $fg$ and $foh$
are bounded at $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: How would you make a proof?

Comment: @Michal Do you know what is bounded.

Comment: I do, but I was thinking about general explanation, not for two specific functions.

Comment: This is a counter example which proves that the product of two unbounded functions can be bounded.

Comment: And why is f times g bounded at (0,∞) ?

Comment: @Michal it is constant $=1$.